# Can't login because of quote (') in email address

Tags: joomla

Using LDAP to login.
If a user has quote `'` in the email address, on login attempt getting this message:

`please enter a valid email address`

Cannot login.

If remove the quote manually in the DB, the message is gone.

Need to keep the quote in the email and be able to login.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

you will need to escape the email address.

i have not tested this but;

in administrator/components/com_login/models/login.php line 38 change

```
'username' => $input->$method->get('username', '', 'USERNAME'),
```

to

```
'username' => addslashes ( $input->$method->get('username', '', 'USERNAME') ),
```